# Regular expression for exact match of a sentence in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a text with many sentence chunks and full sentences. These sentences all have the following formatting:

```
Text=Some aliens try to run into the fields
Text=Some aliens try
Text=Some aliens try to run
```

I want to match the text in the QUERY variable (for current example `'Some aliens try'`).

I'm using the following code:

```
my_query_reg = re.compile("".join(['Text=', QUERY, '$']))
my_query_reg.findall(TEXT)
```

However, my regular expression appears to be incorrect and `findall()` does not return any results, why?

Comment: no, QUERY is a string, stripped of any new lines

Comment: ``re.compile("".join(['Text=', QUERY, '$']),re.MULTILINE)``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$` in your query only matches the very end of your string by default.

Use the [`re.MULTILINE`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE) option to make `$` match the end of *any* line:

```
my_query_reg = re.compile("".join(['Text=', QUERY, '$']), re.MULTILINE)
```

Comment: Also you can fix it other way around, just split you `TEXT` into separate lines and call `findall()` on each line.

Comment: @Mr.Deathless: if you go that route, just doing a simple `in` against the list of lines seems more efficient than a regex search on each line. (Not that I profiled it...)

Answer (score 3):

If I understand what you want, try this:

```
import re

txt='''\
Text=Some aliens try to run into the fields
Text=Some aliens try
Text=Some aliens try to run'''

QUERY='Some aliens try'
print re.findall(r'^(Text={}\s*)$'.format(QUERY), txt, re.M)
# ['Text=Some aliens try']
```

It has the `re.M` flag so that the line begin `^` and line end `$` anchors will match lines with newlines rather than limited to the entire string.

You can also use 'traditional' Python string formatting to insert the QUERY string into the pattern:

```
re.findall(r'^(Text=%s\s*)$' % QUERY, txt, re.M)
```

And you can add various `\s*` as appropriate to compensate for the noisiness of the text.

Don't forget Python's string tests for such a simple example:

```
print [line for line in txt.splitlines() if line.strip().endswith(QUERY)]
# ['Text=Some aliens try']
```

Comment: That would be too easy if I wanted to match only 'Some aliens try' string, what if I need to match 'The moon is black'?

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

TEXT = """Text=Some aliens try to run into the fields
Text=Some aliens try
Text=Some aliens try to run"""

QUERY = 'Some aliens try'

my_query_reg = re.compile('Text=\s*(%s)\s*$' % QUERY,re.M)
print my_query_reg.findall(TEXT)
```

`\s*` in case there would be whitespaces between `=` and the researched string or between the string and the end of the line